# How to change the background color of $(this) element on text changed without postback?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asynchronous

I'm not very strong with JavaScript so pardon the ignorance. I have a webpage where users upload a .XLS/.CSV and review it before submitting the data to our database. The users may edit the cells of the document in our "review" screen before clicking "submit". However, because there may be 150+ rows, I want to implement some client-side functionality that changes the background color of a textbox if the user makes a change to it.

I am able to accomplish this using C#'s `OnTextChanged` event, but I want to accomplish this without any postbacks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTextBoxColor() {
      $(this).style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
</script>
```

The textboxes are implemented in an `<asp:Repeater>`, so I couldn't really implement a `var v = document.getElementById(...)` statement in my function. An example of a textbox I'm trying to call this on:

```html
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtRGMNumber" CssClass="faded--input white full"
     OnChange="changeTextBoxColor()" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RGM Number") %>'>
  </asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Upon editing the text in the textbox, I need the background color of the box to be set to red WITHOUT postbacks.

Comment: I think your question is not related to `C#`. See how the `Repeater` renders the lines, give us an example of the lines displayed in `HTML`, and help you with `JS` only.

Comment: @Baruch I only mentioned the repeater as to clarify why I can't use `var v = document.getElementById(...)`; rather I need to use $(this). My apologies, but I'm a little confused as to what you are asking me to clarify. Do you want me to include the entire `<asp:Repeater>` block? Thanks.

Comment: I think that when you use `Repeater`, it compiles to standard `HTML` code. And when you write `Javascript`, it works on the `HTML` and not on the `Repeater`.
So I think you need to run the page, and do a `view source`, and see what's created in `HTML` (you'll find that the `Repeater` is not there).

Comment: @Baruch Yes, that makes sense; the `<asp:Repeater>` is translated to a simple `<tr>` with many rows. I don't understand how this would change how I go about implementing this function, though. I am not doing anything "repeater-specific" in my JavaScript. I'm only trying to change the `.style.backgroundColor` of `$(this)` in my JS.

Comment: I also do not know, I do not know good Javascript. But I think if you ask how you can paint a whole line when you click on any tag inside it, I think you'll get an answer.

Comment: Do you want to change the background color as soon as the text changes at all? Then you wouldn't want any server side code for this, so as mentioned, c# isn't in the picture at all. The HTML is generated by c# code, but the solution is entirely javascript. Except you'll probably generate the javascript in C# too. You could. I'll try to work up a few examples.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes sir, my goal is to change the background color of the textbox as soon as the text is changed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tiny bit "hacky", but the more I clean it up the less obvious it is what it's doing:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="Some value" 
                                CssClass="js-changeBackgroundColor" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

        </table>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".js-changeBackgroundColor").on("input", function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

First, we're adding a CSS class - `js-changeBackgroundColor` to each one of the server-side text boxes. So when each one is rendered, it will contain this attribute:

```
class="js-changeBackgroundColor"
```

Using a CSS class to "mark" items (instead of to actually apply styles) may be outdated. You could likely do the same thing with some other attribute. But the `js-` prefix indicates that the class is for that purpose. (The prefix doesn't actually do anything - it's just a convention so that a person reading the code can see the difference.)

Then we're adding jQuery to the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, we're executing a script that says, find all of the elements with that class and add an event handler to them. When the "input" event is fired, change the background color to green:

```
<script>
$(".js-changeBackgroundColor").on("input",
    function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    });
</script>
```

This is hardly polished, but you can see it as an introduction to how to mix server-side and client-side code without them stepping on each other.

They do still step on each other just a little bit, though. The server side code doesn't "know" that the client-side code changed the background color. So if you do a postback, the background color will revert back to whatever it was.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a million, Scott!